# Parse inner class of span class text with DOM PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, parsing, dom

I want to parse     **div >ul  > li > div > strong > a**  (LINK and LINK 1) data from website. But I can't get success.

I use **code** to parse dome data:

```
$DTP = retrieve_node_text($data, "//li[@class='coll-1']");
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="tab-detail">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li>
            <div class="coll-1">
                <a href="#">icon</a>
                <strong>
                    <a href="LINK">Link 1</a>
                </strong>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="coll-1">
                <a href="#">icon</a>
                <strong>
                    <a href="LINK">Link 1</a>
                </strong>
            </div>
        </li>
        <ul/>
    </div>
```

Comment: AFAIK `li[@class='coll-1']` doesn't exist in this markup, the class is an attribute of the div that is a child of the `li` elements... There is also no code visible that actually sets about parsing and consuming the given markup: `retrieve_node_text` seems to be a custom function, but you don't provide us with the code for that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpQuery library it is equivalent to jQuery for server side HTML string parsing.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/

I hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: That's not really an answer: link-only answers are discouraged. You fail to _explain_ why/what's wrong with the current approach, and why using a linked third-party resource would help in this particular case (which it probably won't). If an XPath is incorrect, and you find a library that works with a bad xpath, you're basically working with buggy tools.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, this is not buggy tool, I have used may time to parse dom element like jQuery that's why I have suggested. and its very easy library. in this like all documentations are provided please check it. 

Please don't try to discourage other's answer

Comment: I'm not discouraging people from answering, I'm pointing out that, if you check the help section, the answer you posted is not considered a good answer according to the SO guidelines. Link-only answers are actively discouraged, because links break, and the goal of this site is to serve as a future reference. This answer is rendered useless the moment that link breaks. Second: I'm not saying this tool is broken, I'm saying you failed to address the actual _issue_ the OP is having. Look at the markup, then look at the xpath he's using. The XPath is invalid!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, thanks for your suggestions and provide understanding for SO policy.

Comment: If the tool you're linking to does indeed work, then using that library won't solve the OP's problem (because the problem is the XPath). If using the tool you suggest _does_ work with the markup and the XPath the OP posted here, then obviously, the only possible conclusion would be: the tool is broken. the xpath is looking for a `li` element with a `coll-1` class attribute. That element doesn't exist in the given markup. If your library finds that element, it's just plain wrong. I guess what I'm trying to say is: don't recommend another tool if the problem is operator error.

Comment: In this case, it looks to me like the OP's problem is his own code, adding more dependencies is never going to change the code he writes, so he'll keep running into issues. He needs to read through the documentation, and learn some more about xpath IMO